# async tcp connection C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, tcplistener

```
        TcpListener tcpServer = new TcpListener(8080);
        tcpServer.Start();
        tcpServer.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(this.messageRecived), tcpServer);
```

I have some code for accept reading from tcp client, client send massage in this way:

```
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.2", 8080)
        string Str = "it's work";
        byte[] Buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Str);
        client.GetStream().Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
```

the problem is in messageRecived method:

```
    public void messageRecived(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[20000];
        string outData;

        TcpListener server = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;

        server.AcceptTcpClient().GetStream().Read(data, 0, server.Server.ReceiveBufferSize);

        outData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        addLog(outData);

    }
```

When i send message to server the method received run until to this line:

```
server.AcceptTcpClient().GetStream().Read(data, 0, server.Server.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

and in the next iteration it begin from next line to the end of method. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably because you are not closing stream from client, please refer to below link to properly dispose stream from client

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if i add 'server.AcceptTcpClient().GetStream().Read(data, 0, server.Server.ReceiveBufferSize);
            server.AcceptTcpClient().GetStream().Close();' close method work only in the next itteration

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush the client Stream.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.2", 8080)
string Str = "it's work";
byte[] Buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Str);
var stream = client.GetStream()
stream.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
stream.Flush()
```